# How can I use jq 'try-catch' inside of an object construction

Tags: bash, jq, kubectl

The general problem statement is that I have some json data with fields that may or may not exist. Patterns like `try .foo catch "bar"` or `.foo? // "bar"` work just fine on their own, but not inside of an object construction `cat myfile.json | jq -r '{foo: try .foo catch "bar"}'`. Using an object construction is important for my use case, where I need to pass the same input through many filters and format the data nicely for later functions.

The data I'm working with is the output of `kubectl get pods xxxxx -o json`, and the part I'm trying to parse looks like this

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "status": {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "Initialized",
            "message": "foo"
          },
          {
            "type": "Ready"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "status": {
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For each item, if it has `.status.conditions`, I want the message from the first element in `.status.conditions` that has a message. The filter I used looks like this

```
jq -r '.items[] | {message: .status.conditions?|map(select(has("message")).message)[0]?}'
```

The problem is that when it gets to an item that doesn't have a `.status.conditions`, It returns the error `Cannot iterate over null (null)`. This makes sense given that `.status.conditions?` passes `null` to the next filter, `map` which needs to iterate over a list. My attempted solution was to use various ways of `try-catch` to pass an empty list to map instead of null

```
jq -r '.items[] | {message: .status | try .conditions catch [] |map(select(has("message")).message)[0]?}'
jq -r '.items[] | {message: .status.conditions? // []|map(select(has("message")).message)[0]?}'
```

or to use a `?` that includes the `map` call

```
jq -r '.items[] | {message: (.status.conditions?|map(select(has("message")).message)[0])?}'
jq -r '.items[] | {message: .status.conditions?|(map(select(has("message")).message)[0])?}'
```

All of these attempts return `1 compile error` when written inside of an object constructor as shown, and work as expected when written on their own without an object constructor (e.g. `'.items[] | .status.conditions?|(map(select(has("message")).message)[0])?'`)

The jq man page doesn't give any warnings (that I noticed) about how object construction changes the syntax requirements of what's inside, nor how `try-catch` can be affected by being inside an object construction. Any ideas?

Comment: adding parenthesis `jq -r '{foo: (try .foo catch "bar")}'` doesn't work?

Comment: @Fravadona Ah, yes and no. This does work when the last filter is the `try`-ed operation, like in my case `jq -r '{message: .status | (.conditions? // [])}'`. It does not work when I try to pass that on `jq -r '{message: .status | (.conditions? // []) | map...}'`, nor if I put the parenthesis around different parts. Is there some documentation that describes the use of () better than the man page?

Comment: Arg, no that was just a mistake on my part, i tried again and got it to work. Still a bit frustrating that the man page doesn't give a hint about this

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Fravadona, it was just a matter of parentheses. I had tried it at some point and made some mistake or other, but a working solution for my case is

```
jq -r '{message: .status | (.conditions? // []) | map(select(has("message")).message)[0]?}'
```